# How to make API so any one access it provided credentials

Tags: java, database, api-design

i am a front end designer and have a website WWW.EX.COM which have fields like 
Name
email
phone
mysecret and 15 more fields.
and storing these details in the MySQL database everything fines till there.
But i want my own API so other websites can access all fields by providing the credentials.
Que1. In which technology the api can be made.( I know java).
Que2. and how that api can be used to connect database and other site

Some examples like https://juspay.in/docs/api/ec/

i want api like these sites so others developers and websites can use it to access a user information..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYV3w.png)

for more details view image

Comment: thanks for reply  Berkley Lamb i have heard of Auth02 for the purpose of authntication i am intrested in the technology used to design the api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Swagger](https://swagger.io) is a very popular framework for building APIs.  It can even do some code generation for you.  Another option (not free) is [AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/), although you'll get the most bang out of that if you use AWS for your actual services.